# PyInstaller - WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt*.dll

Tags: java, python, pyinstaller, pyjnius

I am trying to execute PyInstaller main.py on my windows 10 machine, I am getting the following warning:

```
3536 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
3701 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
3921 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
4088 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
4258 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
4490 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
4665 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
4858 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
5024 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
5248 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
5567 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
5727 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
5942 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6108 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6275 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6436 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6593 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6752 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6922 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
7090 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
7249 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
7417 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\dlee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
```

I found my DLL in the following directory:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer`

I read the following article (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows) and tried to create a .spec-file using `pyi-makespec main.py` to include my dlls. Below is what my spec file looks like:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\dlee\\eclipse-workspace\\python_java_pyjnius_test'],
             binaries=[('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer','.')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='main')
```

However, it is giving me the same error.

I also tried the following command:
`pyinstaller --add-binary "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer;." main.py`

It still doesn't work. In the end, after I execute main.exe, I always get the following output:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries
```

I am really struggling and really not sure what I did wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Best Regards,
Daniel Lee

Comment: Did you get it to work? I'm having the same issue. I have Visual Studio 2017 and the latest Microsoft Visual C++ update from 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads